# How to encode only 2 chars in path?

Tags: php, encoding

I have a $delete path and a $user_id each include '#' and '@' respectively within the string. How can I replace each with the encoded value %23 and $40.

I tired using str_replace but did not have any luck:
`str_replace($string, array('@', '#'), array('%40', '%23'));`

My full Delete path looks like this:

```
$delete = "http://admin:12345@192.168.245.133/@api/deki/DELETE:users/$user_id/properties/%s";
```

I feel like the $user_id should be pretty simple. For the properties it has to loop through to get all the available properties. You can see the loop below:

```
foreach($xml->property as $property) {
      $name = $property['name']; // the name is stored in the attribute
      curl_fetch(sprintf($delete, $name),'admin','12345');
    }
```

Each property contains a '#', so is there a way that each iteration which modify '#' to be the appropriate value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) wrongly: The first parameter is *search*, the second *replace* and the third *subject*:

> mixed **str_replace** ( mixed *$search* , mixed *$replace* , mixed *$subject* [, int *&$count* ] )

So:

```
str_replace(array('@', '#'), array('%40', '%23'), $string)
```

Comment: @Gumbo I just tried this directly after assigning the $user_id, and after the str_replace I printed it. For some reason, it's still giving me the user_id without the %40 as it should. Any ideas?

Comment: @Aaron: Did you reassign the modified value to the variable?

Comment: @Gumbo Ah, I think that's my issue. So does that mean I need to do $user_id = str_replace(...) ?

Comment: @Aaron: `str_replace` does work with a copy of the variables value and not the variable itself. Otherwise it would need to be passed as reference.

Comment: @Gumbo So how would I correctly work with a copy of the variables value?

Comment: @Aaron: Just assign the returned value of `str_replace` back to your variable. So `$string = str_replace(…);`.

Comment: @Gumbo Cool, that worked. I was being dumb and assigned it back to user_id. Would I be able to use this on the $delete as well? I'm just not sure where it belongs.

Comment: @Gumbo: I figured out where to str_replace for the properties. One things thats strange, I started getting a warning: springf(): too few arguments. Is this coming from the % possibly? Nothing else has changed. If you have any ideas I'd really appreciate it.